# Basic windows include can't be found in release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, release

I have a C++ project developed under VS2019 that works fine using debug mode (x64 with Windows SDK 10.0.18362.0).

But when I try to compile it using release mode I get hundreds of errors such as :

```
    Error (active)  E1696   unable to open source file "ctype.h"    SYABOT_ScanAndControl   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cctype  12  
    Error (active)  E1696   unable to open source file "errno.h"    SYABOT_ScanAndControl   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cerrno  12  
    Error (active)  E1696   unable to open source file "float.h"    SYABOT_ScanAndControl   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cfloat  11  
    Error (active)  E1696   unable to open source file "locale.h"   SYABOT_ScanAndControl   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\clocale 12  
    Error (active)  E1696   unable to open source file "corecrt.h"  SYABOT_ScanAndControl   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\crtdefs.h   10  
    Error (active)  E1696   unable to open source file "stddef.h"   SYABOT_ScanAndControl   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstddef 12  
    Error (active)  E1696   unable to open source file "stdio.h"    SYABOT_ScanAndControl   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdio  12  
    Error (active)  E1696   unable to open source file "stdlib.h"   SYABOT_ScanAndControl   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdlib 13  
    Error (active)  E1696   unable to open source file "math.h" SYABOT_ScanAndControl   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdlib 12  
    Error (active)  E1696   unable to open source file "string.h"   SYABOT_ScanAndControl   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstring 12  
    Error (active)  E1696   unable to open source file "time.h" SYABOT_ScanAndControl   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime   12
```

I am really confused and I haven't found any information to solve this issue on google. I'm hoping someone can help me here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably accidentally checked some kind of "no system include directories" checkbox in the release configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you should check the configuration options in the property page when setting the Windows SDK version.

I suggest you could choose `All Configurations`. And you could also choose `Release` then set the Windows SDK version.

[image]

[image]